# Odds ratio interpretation of dependent and independent variables

Tags: interpretation, odds-ratio, dependent-variable

I am searching for some studies to evaluate the effect of drug x use among patients using drug y.
One study reports the odds ratio for the concurrent use of both drugs.

Can I assume it is the same as the odds ratio for drug x use with drug y as the independent variable?